# iTunes App Store Accepts Non-Native Apps?

Tags: java, iphone, flash, mobile

This question is for anyone that's had personal experience. The question is simple: Does Apple accept iPhone apps that haven't been written using their SDK? Apps can be written using different languages these days, and then compiled into iPhone apps. Does Apple even care?

**Edit**
iPhone apps can be created using Java and Flash CS5, which is the reason this question uses those tags. It's relevant to to developers who are, or have created iPhone apps with those languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They care so much that they made it a violation of the App Store policy to use non-native APIs.

There was enough backlash, that they updated the policy to allow the use of non native APIs.

Comment: Which tool to cross-compile Java to iPhone?

Comment: @Kinderchocolate, I'm not aware of one, but there is mono support, so you might be able to use IKVM.